# Calculating distance function from a piecewise velocity function (pre-calculus)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, piecewise-continuity

This is my very first question here. I am self-studying maths and I am currently doing pre-calculus from Gilbert Strang's textbook "Caculus 1". So I apologize in advance if this question comes across as basic.

I am puzzled by the following problem, which is a recommended problem (not mandatory) for pre-calc:

*An up and down velocity has the following piecewise function*

(1) $v(t) = 2t$  for  $t \leq 3$

(2) $v(t) = 12 - 2t$ for $t > 3$

*Draw the piecewise parabola $f(t)$ . Check that $f(6)$= area under the graph of $v(t)$*.

Now, the area under the graph of $v(t)$ equals 18.

What I find difficult is to find the formula of $f(t)$ (the pieceswise parabola). At first I thought that the two velocity functions are simply the derivatives of the two parabola functions. By "reversing" the derivatives (sorry but I have no knowledge of integrals yet), I  get:

(3) $f(t) = t^2$ for $x\leq3$

and

(4) $f(t) = 12t-t^2$  for $x > 3$

But this cannot be right. Concerning the area under (1) and (2) = 18, obviously if I plug $f(6)$ I get 36, which is wrong. In my understanding, 36 would be the area under (2) if it didn't start from $x > 3$, so without taking into account the fact that this is a piecewise function.

Moreover, if I plot functions (3) and (4), I get a "jump" at $t = 3$, from $f(t)=9$ (from (3)) to $f(t)=27$ (from (4)).

I don't know if one can get a discontinous function from a continuous derivative function, but it seems counterintuitive to me (we simply "changed" the velocity at $x=3$, why the heck should we "jump" from distance 9 to distance 27? Can we teleport?)

My guess is that function (4) is not quite right, and that I should get a continuous piecewise function of parabolas. But I don't know how to proceed mathematically, and I cannot find a worked out solution anywhere.

Most explanations of similar problems I found require knowing integrals.

Can anybody solve this without using integrals and provide a clear explanation to a newbie?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The "velocity times time" produces a change in position, not an absolute position.  So you should add a "starting position" on your functions of $f(t)$.  For the first function we assume/define the position $f(0)=0$, but at $f(3)$ it has gone to $9$ as you pointed out.  You have written $f(t)=12t-t^2$ as if it started at $f(3)=27$, just add a constant to your equation in order to enforce it starts at $f(3)=9$, ie $f(t)=A + 12t-t^2\implies A = -18$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]The relation between $f(t)$ and $v(t)$ is simply that $f(t)=\int_0^t v(s) ds$. So, when $t \leq 3$, you have that
$$
f(t)=\int_0^t 2s ds = [s^2]_0^t = t^2.
$$

But, when $t>3$,
$$
f(t)=\int_0^t v(s) ds = \int_0^3 v(s) ds + \int_3^t v(s) ds = 9+[12s-s^2]_3^t = -t^2+12 t-18.
$$

---

If you wish to avoid integrals, you can just compute the area under the graphics of $v(t)$ up to a generic time $t$. Like before, when $t\leq 3$ the area under the graph (from 0 up to $t$) is the area of a triangle, given by $f(t) = \frac{t \cdot 2t}{2} = t^2$. When $t>3$, the cumulative area is all the area from $t = 0$ to $t=3$, which is 9, plus the area of a trapezoidal region, that you can compute interns of $t$.

Comment: The question asked to avoid the use of integration.

Comment: Missed it! I'll see if I can fix it in a good way.

Comment: Thank you, but actually I solved that part of the question (I found the area under v(t) to be = 18, and I get the reasoning behind it). My issue is this part of the question: "check that f(t) is the area under v(t)". I could simply set f(6) = 18, but is this really the best way to "check", or to demonstrate that indeed f(6) = 18? in other words, in my understanding I would first need to find that f(6) = 18, and only in a second step verify that this is indeed the area under v(t)...

Comment: @serenityp I don't understand your difficulty... If you are able to show that the distance travelled up to $t=6$ is $f(6)$, why not repeat the same reasoning with a generic $t$, instead of $t=6$?